# jsFiddle Character set

Tags: html, character-encoding, meta-tags, jsfiddle

Is there a way I can define the character set, and other info that belongs in `<meta>` tags on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

I know about the "info" section of their side panel, but that doesn't allow `<meta>` tags.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can force a specific character encoding in Firefox and Chrome using the menus...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just put it in the CSS section:

```
</style>
<meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials" />
<style>
```

Test in the Javascript section with the jQuery framework:

```
var desc = $('meta[name="description"]').attr("content");
alert(desc);
```

**UPDATED** Added a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mhart/3fHrt/

Comment: Could you give an example fiddle?

Comment: +1 Now I see what you mean! That's kinda wierd, but it works!

Comment: jsFiddle sticks whatever's in the CSS section between `<style>` tags, then puts that in `<head>`, so you can add anything to `<head>` using this method.